# using integration in matlab over a symbolic value gives a result containing a symbolic value instead of a number value

Tags: matlab, symbols, integral

im trying to intgrate an expression which is a function of a symbolic value "r" over r from a define numeric value ai to ba using the int(expr(r) ,var(=r) ,a ,b) .the result that i get still contains the symbolic value r. what am I doing wrong?

my code: (c,a1,a2,a3,p,A,B and gamma are all constant number values)

```
ai = 1.6e-3;
ba = sqrt(ai.^2 +(B.^2-A.^2)/gamma);    
R = sqrt(gamma.*(r.^2 - ai.^2) +A.^2);    
ERR = (R.^2)./(2.*(gamma.*r).^2)-0.5;     
Ephi = ((gamma.*r).^2)./(2.*(R.^2))-0.5;   
Q = a1.*(ERR.^2) + a2.*(Ephi.^2) + 2.*a4.*ERR.*Ephi;    
W = c.*.5.*exp(Q);    
DWR = (2.*a1.*ERR + 2.*a4.*Ephi).*W;   
DWP = (2.*a2.*Ephi + 2.*a4.*ERR).*W;   
eqintegral = (((r.*gamma).^2)./(R.^2))*DWP-((R.^2)./((r.*gamma).^2))*DWR;    
pi = int(eqintegral,r,ai,ba);
```

a simpler form describing my intention for which I get a number value as intended:

```
syms r;
a = 5;
b = a*5;
g = sqrt(r);
f = r.^2;
D = 4+6*r;
eqintegral = (f*g)/D;
pi = int(eqintegral,r,a,b);
valpi = double(pi);
```

Comment: It contains `r` likely because the symbolic integration didn't work. Symbolic integration is not like following a fixed recipe such as computing 2+2. I don't think one will be productive thinking that way. If you want to numerically evaluate an integral, use numeric methods. In Matlab, that's [`integral`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/integral.html).

Comment: Otherwise, please give some attention to the communication aspect of your question. If you did get a result instead of error message, that means you have a custom-defined `gamma`. What is it? Do others need to know in order to help you? Further to the point, do they need to review *all* of your formulas in order to understand the problem? Can *you* isolate the part that is producing the unexpected behavior? [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) compile some of such basic points

Comment: gamma is a value ranging from 0-1 depends on presets. here it is fixed as 1. the rest of the constant are also numbers except the symbolic value r.
i do not get an error running this script, just a result which is an a partialy integrated function still containing the symbolic value r.

Comment: I've tried running a the script with a different simpler expression containing the symbolic value r instead of eqintegral and I got a valid numeric only value. I could add the different constant here but they are just number values so I don't think that's the problem.
I thought it might be because eqintegral is a complex expression of the value r made of other expressions containing the value r.

Comment: The only time I see use in symbolic integration on definite integrals despite of expecting numerical results is in order to keep track of rational fractions. Even then, symbolic packages are still not the go to. If you don't have specific reasons, using numerical methods is your best bet.